# SSL connection error: SSL certificate validation failure (2026) (SQLDriverConnect) pyodbc?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to Azure MySQL Database Service. I am using

> pyodbc==3.0.3
>
> python 2.7

My Connection string looks like this

```
connection_string = "DRIVER={MySQL};SERVER={server_name}.mysql.database.azure.com;PORT=3306;DATABASE" \
                        "={my_database_name};UID={username@server_name};PWD={password};CHARSET=UTF8;" \
                      "sslca=/home/sachin/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem;sslverify=1"
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

But the same configuration works with mymysql.connector is working fine.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="{username@servername}", password="{password}",
                              host="{server_name}.mysql.database.azure.com",
                              port=3306, database="{database_name}", ssl_ca="/home/sachin//root.crt",
                              ssl_verify_cert=True)
cnx.cursor()
```

I can not use mysql.connector for now. So need some suggestion if any one have faced this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by setting `sslverify=1` to `sslverify=0`.

e.g. for Azure:

```
;sslca={BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem}; sslverify=0; Option=3;'
```

Comment: Note that this disables verification of the certificate which may reduce the security of the system. Disabling the verification only hides the problem; it does not solve it. The solution to the problem is to properly configure your TLS certificate and use a client-local trust store containing the certificate of the server.